# Pycharm python 2.7 list errors

Tags: python, list

I have this code inputted into pycharm on python 2.7:

```
import random
while True:
  aichoice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
  userImp = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ")
  if userImp == "Paper":            
    print(random.choice(aichoice))  
    if aichoice == "Paper":           
      print('Tie!')
```

It should work perfectly fine, but it isn't. I get this error

```
line 6, in <module>
    userImp = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Paper' is not defined
```

which makes no sense. I even put the exact same code in repl and it worked fine, as expected. What is the issue?

Comment: Try to delete Python compiled/cached files:  Right-click a project or directory, where Python compiled files should be deleted from -> From the context menu, choose **Clean Python compiled files**.

Answer (score 0):

Running `help(input)` says:

```
input(...)
    input([prompt]) -> value

    Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

In other words, when you type "Paper", that `eval` step is executing the code you typed in, as though you typed `Paper` in the repl. For instance if you type `"Pa" + "per"` into the input prompt, it will do what you expect. If you type in `import os; os.system('rm -rf /')` at the input prompt, you're in for a very bad surprise. Note: do not actually do this to see if it actually works. It does.

`input` in Python 2.7 is super dangerous. Don't ever use it.

`raw_input` is the function you want here. Or better, switch to Python 3 where `input` does what you'd expect it to without the surprise.

Comment: How do I upgrade it from 2.7 to 3

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't use Pycharm. But be aware that Python 2 is officially dead now (see https://pythonclock.org) so if you're just getting started with Python, you'll definitely want to learn version 3.